# Can I do multiple exercise-verification sequences with jMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmock

As a disclaimer, I have simplified and generified the example on purpose to prevent out-of-topic answers. I acknowledge that each unit test has to test only a small part of functionality, but in this case I want to test concurrency behaviour, using something like a state-machine approach. I have a Java component that is provided with a lambda function and an ExecutorService as parameters and executes the lambda function using the provided executor. I want to test that the lambda function is called asynchronously, which I managed using Mockito (providing a mock ExecutorService and using ArgumentCaptor to capture the lambda function). The code is like the following:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
ExecutorService mockExecutor = mock(ExecutorService.class);
Consumer<Integer> lambda = mock(Consumer.class);

Component component = new Component(mockExecutor, lambda)

component.call()
verify(mockExecutor)
      .submit(runnableCaptor.capture())
verify(lambda, never())
      .accept(anyInteger())

runnableCaptor.getValue().run()
verify(lambda)
      .accept(any())
```

I have confirmed that this test verifies exactly what I need. To my knowledge, Mockito provides this capability to provide consecutive groups of exercise-verify, but after reading the documentation, it seems that jMock allows setting up all the verifications in advance and all at once.

**Would there be a way to perform the same testing using jMock ?**